# C++: Expected a declaration

Tags: c++

I am a complete noob at programming and I am having multiples errors that says "expected a declaration"
A project was assigned to us that required to create a text base game with characters attacking opponents.
We are to make characters and when we tell them to attack we must enter the correct key to attack.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Opponent;
int showOpponentHealth(int OpponentHealth, int Attack);
int showHealth(int Health, int OpponentAttack);
int showMagic(int Magic);
{ //Error: expected a declaration
public:
    Opponent() : OpponentAttack(0), OpponentHealth(3);
    {
        OpponentAttack = rand() % 100;
        OpponentHealth = rand() % 6 + 10;
    }
}
int getAttack(Opponent);
{ //Error: expected a declaration
    AttRoll = Rand() % 100
    if (AttRoll < getAtt)
        hit
    {
        AttType = 1 - 3
        if (AttType == 1)
            return 30
        else if (AttType == 2)
        return 50
        else if (AttType == 3)
        return 70
    }

    float character::getHeal()
    {
        magicCost = magic - 6;
        Heal = rand() % 3 + 5;
        cout << "Heal value= " << heal << ".\n";
        return Heal;
    }
}
void Battle()
{
    int Health = rand() % 6 + 10;
    int OpponentHealth = rand() % 6 + 10;
    int hit;
}
long timeTest()
{
    //seed the random number generator
    srand(GetTickCount64());
    //rand will give a number between 0 and max integer value
    int waitTime = rand() % 5 + 1;
    for (int i = waitTime; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout << "*";
        Sleep(1000); //wait for 1 second
    }
    char typeThis = rand() % 26 + 97;
    cout << typeThis << ":";
    char playerResponse;

    //this is the window function I'm using to get the time: ULONGLONG WINAPI GetTickCount64(void);
    ULONGLONG startTime = GetTickCount64();

    cin >> playerResponse;

    ULONGLONG endTime = GetTickCount64();

    if (playerResponse != typeThis)
        return -1;
    long deltaTime = endTime - startTime;

    return deltaTime;
}
do  //syntax error
{  //Error: expected a declaration
    cout << " Attack Opponent? \n Yes = 1\n"
        cin >> Attack Opponent;
    if (AttackOpponent == 1)
    {
        OpponentHealth = showOpponentHealth(OpponentHealth, Attack);
        Health = showHealth(health, OpponentAttack);
        cout << "You attacked the Opponent with a light attack.";
        cout << "The Opponent now has " << OpponentHealth << "health left.";
        if (OpponentHealth <= 0)
        {
            cout << "You Win!";
        }
        else if (OpponentHealth > 0)
        {
            cout << "Opponent attacks back";
            cout << "You have" << Health << "health left,";
        }

        else if (AttackOpponent == 2)
            cout << "You attacked the Opponent with a medium attack.";
        cout << "The Opponent now has " << OpponentHealth << "health left.";
        {  //Error: expected a declaration
        else if (AttackOpponent == 3)
            cout << "You attadcked the Opponent with a heavy attack.";
        cout << "The Opponent now has " << Opponent Health << "health left.";
        }
    }  //Error: expected a declaration
    int showOpponentHealth(int OpponentHealth, int Attack)
    {
        OpponentHealth = OpponentHealth - Attack;
        return OpponentHealth;
    }
    int showHealth(int Health, int OpponentAttack)
    {
        Health = Health - OpponentAttack;
        return Health;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Try the timeTest: " << timeTest() << endl;

    int Health = rand() % 6 + 10;
    if (Health <= 0)
        cout << "You Died. Game Over." << endl;

    int Magic = 10
    else (Magic <= 0)
        cout << "No more Magic." << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return0;
}
```

the errors pop up at the brackets and at "do"

Comment: You put the do/while loop in global scope, that's illegal... What did you expect from this? (PS: `int getAttack(Opponent);` you have an extra `;`)

Comment: You have many syntax problems here. You should re-read the chapter in your book about defining functions and about defining classes. Which book are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Your do{ ... } loop is outside of any function. It must be inside of a function - the compiler is telling you it expects a declaration of a function like:

```
long timeTest()
```

Did you mean for the do-loop to be inside timeTest()?